# Drupal 8 - Display one image from multifield based on the title attribute

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I'm working on a `Drupal` 8 project and having issues trying to access one particular image of an image `multifield`, eg `{{field_images}}`.

I have a View with Exposed Filters which returns a list of nodes based on selected taxonomy terms. One of those taxonomy terms,  has values that may match the title field of images contained within `field_images`.

The view displays a teaser list of content based on the filters, which then links to the full node content page.

Normally, the node list returned in the view will only display the first image from the `multifield`, displayed in the template like this `{{ content.field_images.0}}` or by simply limiting the images returned in the view itself.

However, in the case that an exposed filter value in the view, say "`bathroom`" is selected, I want to be able to find an image from field_images that has "`bathroom`" in the title and display that instead.

Is there any way using either twig logic or views that I can achieve this?

Thanks so much for any assistance anyone may have!

Comment: You would probably wanna ask this here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/